# Making users wait to answer their questions hindering a new user's progress?

Tags: discussion, answers

Ok so SE has this feature that doesn't let new users answer their own questions in like 6 hours or something. While I appreciate that this helps cut down on whatever big-city problems stack overflow has I've run into two questions where this kind of sucks:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/61678/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-inkscape-not-starting-fixed
- [Ubuntu @myLaptop will boot only when failsafe graphics mode selected(several errors)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61559/ubuntu-mylaptop-will-boot-only-when-failsafe-graphics-mode-selectedseveral-erro)

As you can see, even with the "you can't answer yet" limitation, people are trying to do the right thing and just editing the answer into their question.

Perhaps newish user self-answers should go into a queue like the anonymous edits to be approved, that way the user can post their solution right away (and have better feedback than just sticking them in a dungeon). Or since we don't have the same flood of crap questions as SO maybe the threshold of being able to answer your own question can be relaxed.

Comment: Definitely a +1.

Comment: Well, same goes for comments. Comments might be second-class citizens, but they often build the base for an answer - instead we have to deal with non-answers over non-answers.

Comment: yeah but new users can always comment on their own questions.

Comment: I've been thinking a lot about this as well. It's not constructive to restrict users in this area.

Comment: I run into this issue every now and then. A new user will mark their question as solved with an edit, I'll come by to ask them to post it as an answer instead, then they'll run into this error and ask me about it, which I completely forgot about. By the ways, this privilege of not being able to answer your own question without a wait period if you have less than 100 rep does not show up in the [list of privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges), so we have no way of knowing beforehand.

Answer (score 8):

I'd go with your suggestion of an answer queue for new users. We already have enough 10k+ users to handle such situations, so it would be nice to implement it.

Maybe we could even let 7.5k users pitch in here. It would be another little encouragement for dedicated AU users who have not yet reached 10k.

Comment: I think you mean 7.5k. Otherwise .75K is just 750, no?

Comment: @root45: thanks was a mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're radically underestimating the amount of noise self-"answers" this is already preventing on your site, and instead focusing on the rare cases when it is a hindrance.

I would not support removing this new user restriction.

Comment: See my answer..